# 3 part formula for linking string data from different / same cell

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, spreadsheet

```
A1
Michael Lewis

B1
'at'xyz
```

I would like an individual formula to do each of the following

```
Michael.lewis@xyz.com (First Name ‘dot’ Surname)
M.lewis@xyz.com (First initial ‘dot’ Surname)
mlewis@xyz.com (First initialSurname)
```

Id like a drop down menu to change which formula I am using.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get exactly what you need, but here goes.

I had to translate all the formulas back to english because my work computer is in a different locale but I think it's right (in case there's a typo I missed)

The formulas you asked for in respective order:
(B11 = name, B12 = email domain)

```
=LEFT(B11;SEARCH(" ";B11)-1) & "." & RIGHT(B11; LEN(B11)-SEARCH(" ";B11))& "@" &B12

=LEFT(B11;1) & "." & RIGHT(B11; LEN(B11)-SEARCH(" ";B11))& "@" &B12

=LEFT(B11;1) & RIGHT(B11; LEN(B11)-SEARCH(" ";B11))& "@" &B12
```

Then you can just add a data validation list pointing to the cells you write the formulas on and it should work as intended, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing first name in cell A1:

```
= LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Accessing last name in cell A1:

```
= RIGHT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Accessing first initial in cell A1:

```
= LEFT(A1,1)
```

Getting passed the `'at'` in cell B1 and only returning `xyz`:

```
= RIGHT(B1,5)
```

Therefore, for example, `<first name>.<last name>` is:

```
= LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&"."&RIGHT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&"@"&RIGHT(B1,5)&".com"
```

If you remove the `'at'` from cell B1 and just have `xyz`, then the formula above could be slightly simplified; You can substitute `RIGHT(B1,5)` simply with `B1`.

Also, the `LOWER` function converts all text to lowercase.

For example to get the lowercase first letter of first name, formula would be:

```
= LOWER(LEFT(A1,1))
```